# h2 database 3 table delete in one query

Tags: mysql, h2

I have 3 tables:-

```
customer(customer_id)
sales(sales_id, customer_id)
salesdetails(salesdetails_id, sales_id)
```

How can I delete the customer and also 2 other related table data in one query?

I stucked here:-

```
DELETE FROM customer, sales, salesdetails
USING customer, sales, salesdetails
WHERE customer.customer_id = sales.customer_id 
AND sales.sales_id = salesdetails.sales_id 
AND customer.customer_id = 'C0001';
```

Note:I am using and new to h2 database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your table add the delete method 'cascade'.
Example:

Customer:

```
 CREATE TABLE customer(
  customer_id integer primary key auto_increment
);
```

Sales:

```
CREATE TABLE sales(
     sales_id integer primary key auto_increment,
     FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer(id)
       ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

This way, when you delete a customer, all the related sales will be deleted too.